# Multiple values for one field in comma-separated values .csv format

Tags: csv

Is it possible to have multiple values under the same field in a .csv file?

I have an "email" field on my webpage, and the user may optionally type in multiple addresses. I want my .csv file to be able to handle an arbitrary number of "email" values. How can I achieve this? The .csv is read by a third party program which I cannot modify.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Yes. You can have multiple values in one filed of a CSV file.

If the multiple values are separated by space you need not do anything special but if the values are separated by a comma, you need to enclose the entire field in double quotes.

Example:

```
Name,E-mail    
foo,foo@a.com foo foo@b.com
bar,"bar@a.com,bar@b.com"
```

Comment: Ok, so if I have fields: FirstName,Email,Lastname it could be: Mike, mike@aol.com mike@gmail.com mike@hotmail.com, Hanson ?

Comment: That looks good. The only thing you need to ensure that if a comma appears in a field, the field must be enclosed in `"..."`

Comment: What if, for a field user can give multiple values, but each of those value can have a comma in it. e.g.. user can give multiple postal addresses. e.g..

101, Sunset Blvd, California. AND
301, Mulholand Drive, Chicago.

Here i cannot do this:

"101, Sunset Blvd, California,301, Mulholand Drive, Chicago"

As it will split the values inside the quotes in 6 values, instead of 2. So what's the right and standard way to do it.

Thanks for help.

Comment: @vinit by this point I'd be considering multiple rows (or a relational DB)