# ML.Net Data.SaveAsText CSV file cannot be loaded by Model Builder

Tags: c#, .net, ml.net, ml.net-model-builder

I export my current ML.Net Data to a CSV with this function

```
using (var stream = File.Create("c:\\temp\\aidata.csv"))
             mlContext.Data.SaveAsText(trainData, stream);
```

The saved data looks ok, but when I try to load the CSV with the [ML.Net Model Builder](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/machinelearning-ai/ml-dotnet/model-builder) I get this error:

> Data Error: Unable to infer column types of the file provided.

Note:
I also have vector columns in the CSV

The CSV file looks like [this](https://pastebin.com/xBBrpcaM) (I have removed some colums to be smaller).

If I load the data file with mlContext.Data.LoadFromTextFile("c:\temp\aidata.csv"); 
it loads it without any error, but the Model Builder fails to load it.

Comment: What does the data look like? Just tried the `SaveAsText` on a project I had and didn't get the error.

Comment: it looks like this https://pastebin.com/xBBrpcaM  (I have removed some some colums to be smaller)

Comment: You do not have a CSV file.  CSV has one header row (optional) with data normally separated with character like a comma. You have lots of header rows and the data is separated with TABs.  You may be able to import as a Tab delimited file.

Comment: @jdweng this is the CSV file exported by ML.Net, it is a CSV file which contains vectors! (sub-arrays for each record).

Comment: You may want to change the extension from csv (comma separated values) to tsv (tab separated values) like the examples on on the link you provided.  The error may be due to the extension of the filename being wrong.

Comment: @MarioM Was data removed as well as the columns? It does look like there are more data than there are columns from the paste bin.

Comment: @Jon No, the data was left there, here is a complete data file, it gets deleted after the first download https://file.io/euxcP5

Answer (score 1):

As a matter of fact the file can not be `.csv` just because it's saved with the extension. It needs transformation like this:

```
static class MLCsvHelper
{
    private class ColumnDefinition
    {
        private readonly int end;

        public string Name { get; }
        public int Start { get; }
        public int Count { get; }

        public ColumnDefinition(string name, int start, int count) =>
            (Name, Start, Count, end) = (name, start, count, start + count - 1);

        public override string ToString() =>
            $"{Name}:\"{Start}:{end}\"";
    }

    public static void Patch(string file, out string csv)
    {
        csv = Path.ChangeExtension(file, "patched.csv");
        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(file);

        var columns = lines.TakeWhile(line => line.Contains("#@"))
            .Where(line => line.Contains("col=")).Select(line => GetColumn(line))
            .ToArray();

        var data = lines.SkipWhile(line => line.Contains("#@")).Skip(1)
            .Select(line => line.Split('\t')).ToArray();

        var res = new[] { string.Join("\t", columns.Select(column => column.Name)) }
            .Concat(data.Select(item => string.Join("\t", columns.Select(column => GetValue(column, item)))));

        File.WriteAllLines(csv, res.ToArray());
    }

    private static ColumnDefinition GetColumn(string line)
    {
        var items = line.Split(new[] { '=', ':' });
        var name = items[1];
        var range = items.Last().Split('-');
        var start = int.Parse(range.First());
        var last = int.Parse(range.Last());
        var count = last - start + 1;
        return new ColumnDefinition(name, start, count);
    }

    private static string GetValue(ColumnDefinition column, string[] data)
    {
        var chunk = data.Skip(column.Start).Take(column.Count);
        var value = string.Join("\t", chunk);
        if (chunk.Skip(1).Any())
            value = $"\"{value}\"";
        return value;
    }
}

MLCsvHelper.Patch("zvVEYT", out var csv);
```

[image]

Comment: I have tried this method, and yes the patched file is a little smaller and contains the quotes which are not in the file after the first SaveAsText....but the model builder still cannot load the file, I get the same error...:(

Comment: Here is my complete CSV file, saved with your patch
https://file.io/UvlDDi

Comment: @Mario M, it's file not found.

Comment: they have deleted the file, I don't know why

Comment: Try this now https://file.io/zvVEYT   I believe after the first download it gets deleted

Comment: Did you get it ?

Comment: @MarioM, yes, thanks, got the file. Will take a look.

Comment: @MarioM, I wrote a util to transform the file to real csv. See renewed answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198085/discussion-between-alex-and-mario-m).

Comment: @MarioM, did you try it? I even got it trained with accuracy of 75%.

Comment: wow! yes it works now! But I have to check if the vectors are loaded as vectors and not as a single value

Comment: the float vector columns are converted to strings, and the non vector columns are float. That means the vectors are loaded into a single string which is not ok

Comment: Try to generate the code with the model builder, and look in ModelInput.cs, there are no vectors in any column

Comment: @MarioM, I see it. Will try to find out something.

Comment: @MarioM, sadly, I was looking for the solution whole day and didn't manage to. I tried different formatting, tried `CsvHelper`, some other approaches. Nothing. The Model Builder is not open source, so one can not fix it for personal use. They got [feature request](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/issues/3684). Someone else is experiencing this [string-problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57454880/using-ml-net-model-builder-to-predict-value-at-date-gives-strange-results).

Comment: I know, I was also looking for the source code of model builder.

Comment: @MarioM, they try different approaches one by one searching for the best one. One can implement it with help of [samples](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning-samples).

Comment: are you saying to make my own model builder with AutoML ?

Comment: @MarioM, yes, the only way, unless they fix it or go open source. I guess it will be mostly copy-pasting from those samples and simple code generation.

Comment: @MarioM, how is it going? Any success with the problem?

Comment: not yet, I worked on a different part of the project. Also they released a newer version of Model Builder but it still does not support vectors.

Comment: I have created an automated AutoML Regression test, I got results for 11 tests but it freezes after FastForest without any error, I got the results using a progresshandler

Comment: @MarioM, did you try inspecting event viewer or profiling?

Comment: no, but I tried LightGbm regression which was found by AutoML to be an accurate prediction and sadly with live data is not. Now I am looking for a C# deep learning library with GPU support and I can't find one.

Answer (score 0):

As @jdweng said in comments. The file you provided is not in a correct csv format (columns and values are seperated by `";"`). It does however look like tsv format(columns and values are seperated by tabs).

It should work if you try saving your text as a tsv file instead.

Also, the ML.Net video example is using tsv format.

Comment: I have renamed the file to .tsv and tried to load it in Model Builder, but it still does not recognize it. Again, it is a file saved by ML.Net with Data.SaveAsText, it should recognize it's own format.

Comment: How can I save it as a tsv from ML.Net data? there is only one function, SaveAsText

Comment: Looks like there is a separator character option : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/how-to-guides/load-data-ml-net

Comment: I found it alot easier to just convert to csv and run it from there. Does your file contain all the "#@" as in your pastebin link? if so, does it work if you remove that?

Comment: @D.Dahlberg Yes it contains all the "#@" ...I have removed the characters and now I get 2 errors instead of one...Data Error: Unable to infer column types of the file provided.
Data Error: Unable to split the file provided into multiple, consistent columns.

Comment: @D.Dahlberg if I load the data with mlContext.Data.LoadFromTextFile("c:\\temp\\aidata.csv"); it works. But the Model Builder cannot load it...I also tried a smaller file (2MB) instead of 15MB the original file and same result.

Comment: I copied the content from your link without all the ”#@” parameters and serperated the columns with ; and placed your data on separate lines and saved as csv and it worked! I could train the model and finish

Comment: @D.Dahlberg can you paste a small portion of your CSV which have vectors to pastebin? So I can see what is the difference between yours and mine

Comment: Here's the [link](https://pastebin.com/DSgpKbST). based on your file I interpreted the columns to be like that. Was it wrong?

Comment: It was wrong.. here's a new [link](https://pastebin.com/YvN4y7QB). Both files worked for me though

Comment: @D.Dahlberg but you don't have vectors in this CSV,

Comment: @D.Dahlberg these normal CSV files work, but as I said I have data with vectors (more than 1 record for some of the fields)

Comment: @MarioM Hmm.. maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3853647/8380785) answer could work then?

Comment: @D.Dahlberg and how can I save it as TSV when there is only one SaveAsText function?

Comment: @D.Dahlberg it seems that model builder cannot load CSV files with vector columns

Comment: @MarioM Yeah sorry I can’t get that to work either! Could splitting to separate columns work for you?

Comment: I need vectors, because I have more than half of the columns with over 1000 values each