# Using ML.NET Model Builder to predict value at Date gives strange results

Tags: c#, machine-learning, ml.net

I am trying to predict home values in the future near my. Here is a sample of the data set.
    [image: Mean Home Value Over Time]

after choosing the price prediction preset I let the model train after setting value as the label.

Here are the results: 
[image]

The issue is I don't think the model treats the Date column as a date. I enter in dates as strings to the prediction engine and the results are awful. The prediction engine can only predict values for the dates it trained on. Anything before or after is the same prediction over and over again and isn't even close. Does anyone have any advice on how to get the model to understand this is a linear timeline to predict values in the  future?

Here are the auto generated classes

```
using Microsoft.ML.Data;

namespace MyMLAppML.Model.DataModels
{
    public class ModelInput
    {
        [ColumnName("Date"), LoadColumn(0)]
        public string Date { get; set; }


        [ColumnName("Value"), LoadColumn(1)]
        public float Value { get; set; }


    }
}
```

and

```
namespace MyMLAppML.Model.DataModels
{
    public class ModelOutput
    {
        public float Score { get; set; }
    }
}
```